# How can I find out what's denying permission to access a path?

Tags: 6, users

user/uid/edit is giving permission denied where uid = the current user's uid. The permissions all look correct. Is there any way to find out what exactly is denying the permission?

Answer (score 0):

Users should always be able to edit their own profile. The access callback used for "user/%user_category/edit" is [user_edit_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_edit_access/6), which contains the following code:

```
return (($GLOBALS['user']->uid == $account->uid) || user_access('administer users')) && $account->uid > 0;
```

When the currently logged-in user tries to edit his/her account, the function returns `TRUE`, which means s/he has access to the edit form.

There could be a third-party module that altesr the access callback for that menu item, and which is using code that doesn't allow the currently logged-in user to edit his/her own account, or that doesn't consider such a case.

Comment: I figured out what was causing it, but I don't understand why. Perhaps you can enlighten me. In hook_menu_alter I put this in order to hide the edit tab: $items['user/%user/edit']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK; I didn't want that tab there, preferring to link the user to the edit page myself. Apparently this also caused permission denied.

Comment: If you are using Drupal 6, the menu item is defined for "user/%user_category/edit" not "user/%user/edit."